# Replacing partial with AJAX in Rails 4: no errors and no updated data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For the following I'm not receiving any errors and my list-partial is being loaded again after executing the like_oneliner method. But the changed data (`oneliner.users.count` and the `if/else` for `!joined(oneliner)` are not refreshing) isn't showing.

I'm trying to change a button class with an upvote and downvote and try to use the build-in AJAX functionality for it.

*models/campaign.rb*

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :oneliners
has_many :general_connections
```

*models/oneliner.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :users, through: :general_connections
belongs_to :campaign
```

*models/general_connection.rb*

```
belongs_to :oneliner
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :campaign
```

*models/user.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :oneliners, through: :general_connections
has_many :campaigns
```

*controllers/general_connection.rb*

```
def like_oneliner
  @oneliner = Oneliner.find(params[:oneliner_id])
  current_user.general_connections.create(oneliner: @oneliner)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end

def unlike_oneliner
  @general_connection = GeneralConnection.where("oneliner_id = ? AND user_id = ?", params[:oneliner_id], current_user.id).first
  @oneliner = @general_connection.oneliner

  @general_connection.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

*views/campaigns/show.html.erb*

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="collection">
        <% @oneliners.each do |oneliner| %> 
            <%= render partial: 'oneliners/list', locals: { oneliner: oneliner } %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*views/oneliners/_list.html.erb*

```
<li class="collection-item avatar">
  <i class="circle black"><%= oneliner.users.count %></i>
  <span class="title"><%= oneliner.title %></span>
  <p><%= timeago_tag oneliner.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 100.days.ago %> / <%=t 'list.employee' %><%= oneliner.user.name %>
  </p>

  <% if !joined(oneliner) %>
    <%= form_tag(onelinerlike_path, remote: true) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'oneliner_id', oneliner.id %>
        <%= button_tag 'thumb_up', id: "#{ dom_id(oneliner) }", class: "secondary-content material-icons grey-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_tag(onelinerunlike_path, remote: true) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'oneliner_id', oneliner.id %>
      <%= button_tag 'thumb_up', id: "#{ dom_id(oneliner) }", class: "secondary-content material-icons orange-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

*views/general_connection/like_oneliner.js.erb*

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@oneliner) %>').replaceWith(<%= j render partial: 'oneliners/list', locals: {oneliner: @oneliner} %>");
```

The like and unlike methods do works, and I see a small change in the Timeago string (It changes for example from `2 months` in `2 months ago`), but that's it. The `oneliner.users.count` and the `if/else` for `!joined(oneliner)` only show the new data when I refresh the page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `$('#<%= dom_id(@oneliner) %>')` this gives a button element which you are replacing. You should be replacing the whole partial by specifying it's id/class.

Comment: Yes, this was a big part of it, and it leaded to the conclusion that I was trying to give `render partial:` and id, instead of the partial itself. It's solved, thanks! Can you put the above into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Would be glad to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#<%= dom_id(@oneliner) %>')` this gives a button element which you are replacing. You should be replacing the whole partial by specifying it's id/class.